# How to implement behaviour in multiple classes?

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

Suppose n classes, each one of those got the same behavior at insertion in database:

1. create connection
2. query definition
3. data for query definition
4. error handling(in case duplicated or integrity errors in database)
5. close connection

Some of the classes don't need this implementation, others need one implementation(says insert_user implementation) and other ones need two or more implementation(insert_reasons, insert_reason_video each one of those with different query, data definition and error handling)

How can I avoid copy/paste code. I'm coding in python

```
class One:
    def insert_objects(self, objects=None):
        db, cursor = open_connection()
        query_insert_object = """INSERT INTO objects (name, model_id)
        VALUES (%s,(SELECT id FROM models WHERE name=%s));"""
        try:
            for object in objects:
                object_data = (object, self.name)
                cursor.execute(query_insert_object, object_data)
            db.commit()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            if e.msg == "Column 'model_id' cannot be null":
                print("model_id no ha sido insertado, inserte el modelo")
            if e.msg == "Duplicate entry 'perrito-3' for key 'name'":
                print("model.name-object.name previamente insertado para el modelo: {}".format(self.name))
            db.rollback()
        finally:
            close_connection(db, cursor)

    def insert_model(self):
        db, cursor = open_connection()
        query_insert_model = """INSERT INTO models(name) VALUES (%s);
        """
        data_model = (self.name)
        try:
            cursor.execute(query_insert_model, data_model)
            db.commit()
        except IntegrityError a e:
            print("model.name previamente insertado con valor: {}".format(self.name))
            db.rollback()
        finally:
            close_connection(db, cursor)

class Two:
    def insert_user(self):
        db, cursor = open_connection()
        query_insert_user = """INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES (%s,%s);"""
        data_user = (self.id, self.name)
        try:
            cursor.execute(query_insert_user, data_user)
            db.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            print("user.id previamente insertado con valor: {}".format(self.id))
            db.rollback()
        finally:
            close_connection(db, cursor)
.
.
.
class N:
    def insert(self):
        """Generalization of above code"""
        db, cursor = open_connection()
        query = get_query()
        data = get_data()
        try:
            execute_insert()
        except:
            error_handling()
        finally:
            close_connection()
```

Note: I've already seen Strategy Pattern but still no found solution for multiple implementations
EDIT:

I can't understand how the solution

```
class InsertBehevior:
    def insert(self, query):
            db, cursor = open_connection()
            try:
                cursor.execute(query)
                db.commit()
            except IntegrityError as e:
                # Each method has different error handling and
                # each class can have multiple insertion methods
                # so no error_handling can be overwrite in subclass
                error_handling()
            finally:
                close_connection(db, cursor)

def One:
    #Error handling on both methods would be the same
    def insert_videos(self):
        query = function_to create_videos_query()
        insert(query)

    def insert_videos_reason(self):
        query = function_to_create_videos_reason_query()
        insert(query)
```

and I don't like the idea to create a callable and pass it as an argument due it's a functionality of python and not for all object-oriented language. That's why i'm asking for a design pattern solution or something like that

Comment: How about inheriting from a base class that has all the common functionality defined?

Comment: Then question would be, How can I implement multiple behaviors in the same class and use them by different names such as class1.insert_video() and class1.insert_video_reason()?

Comment: The answer is, abstraction. In general, if you find yourself copying or typing the same code twice, you'll want to put it into a reusable function. For example, you could make a function to dynamically build the strings for the SQL transaction depending on certain input parameters.

Comment: Ok, I think got your idea, to create a base class which has a insert method with params query: str, given query must be define in implementation of methods and execute the same, the problem is that I really care about error handling, and I don't know how to define different error handling and pass it to the base class function

Comment: If your error handling has a pattern, maybe you can do that. Why not send the error log you are printing to the base class function. 
Or send the table specific parameter to construct the log into the base class function. You can handle all the possible errors in union too in base class function, right?

Comment: Error handlers are pretty dissimilar and very specific, althought they need class information in order to work.

Comment: Also, sometimes the try block would change since some times the method is needed to insert multiple rows, an opening and closing connection would not ve an óptima option